# Feature engineering: including counter-parties of a transaction in a dataset

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering, fraud-detection

### Background

Say I have a dataset of transfers between bank accounts structured like so:

```
from,     to,      timestamp,             amount
ACT_1,    ACT_2,   2019-01-01 23:59:00,   $123.67
ACT_2,    ACT_5,   2019-02-11 07:23:00,   $347.10
...
```

The same account can appear in either the `from` or the `to` column and can occur multiple times.

I have another table, that indicates whether an account is a "bad actor" or not:

```
account_number, category
ACT_1,          clean
ACT_2,          fraud
ACT_3,          clean
ACT_4,          clean
ACT_5,          drugs
...
```

I was to classify all account numbers in the dataset into the possible categories. I would really appreciate some advice with determining how to create features for my training dataset.

Here are some ideas I had:

### Throw out the `to` counter-party.

Final schema would look something like this:

```
account_number, AVG(timestamp), MAX(timestamp), MIN(timestamp), SUM(amount), COUNT(*), ...
```

*What I don't like about this*: I suspect bad actors transact with other bad actors. Throwing out the counter-parties would lose this relationship

### Include the counter-parties as binary columns.

Final schema would look something like this:

```
account_number, transactedWithAct1, transactedWithAct2, transactedWithAct3, ..., AVG(timestamp), MAX(timestamp), MIN(timestamp), SUM(amount), COUNT(*), ...
```

*What I don't like about this:* My final dataset has over 600,000 unique accounts (I would need to have over 600,000 columns per row if I used this method)

### Conclusion

If anyone has any clever ways of representing counter-parties or any advice on better representations for the existing columns, I would very much appreciate it.